# Has the Delphi Win32 VCL been Fuzz Tested?

Tags: delphi, vcl, fuzzing

To anyone's knowledge has the Delphi Win32 VCL ever been fuzz tested?

Comment: I don't understand the role of this question. can you edit it, so we can understand why are you interested if VCL code was fuzz-tested? it is related to a project you want to do?

Comment: Fuzz testing would likely be pointless for the vast majority of the VCL since the VCL is not expected to survive being sent random data.

Comment: My apologies about the acceptance of questions.  "the VCL is not expected to survive being sent random data" was my guess, but i haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 3):

ask this guy http://blogs.embarcadero.com/chrispattinson. He is director of quality assurance at Embarcadero and he does answer comments on his blog.

edit:  he even puts his email on his blog, so you can email him directly.